# Assign click event after an element was created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, instead of having a form in the HTML, I decided to create the form on fly and append it to another element (in my case a `<section>`, but that will be an option in the near future).

I'm using this method:

```
var formWrapper = ['<div class="content-login">','</div>'];

var form = [
    '<form name="login-form" class="login-form" method="post" action="#">',
        '<fieldset class="login-fields">',
            '<fieldset class="username-wrapper">',
                '<label for="username" class="user-img"><img src="assets/gfx/user.png" alt="Username" /></label>',
                '<input type="text" name="username" class="username" placeholder="Username" value="" autocomplete="off" />',
            '</fieldset>',
            '<fieldset class="password-wrapper">',
                '<label for="password" class="pass-img"><img src="assets/gfx/password.png" alt="Password" /></label>',
                '<input type="password" name="password" class="password" placeholder="Password" value="" autocomplete="off" />',
            '</fieldset>',
            '<fieldset class="login-wrapper">',
                '<button type="submit" name="login" class="login">Login</button>',
            '</fieldset>',
        '</fieldset>',
    '</form>'       
];

setTimeout(function () {
    $(formWrapper.join('')).appendTo('section').hide();
    $(form.join('')).appendTo('.content-login');
    $('.content-login').fadeIn('slow');
}, 1500);
```

This way I have a nice fade in effect and it will give me the opportunity to change whatever I want after I fully develop it.

But my question is in fact the following: I have a form, so of course I will use Ajax to submit it, and I already have the script for that. The thing is now, when I click on the button, the .click event does not occur, it only takes me to the default action of the form which is "#" in my case. Why is that ?

Here is the other part of the script, for a better understanding :

```
$('.login-form .login').click(function(){
    if($('input.username').val() == "" || $('input.password').val() == "")
    {
        console.log('Please enter Username & Password');
        $('.login-form').effect("shake", { distance: 40, times: 2 }, 100);
        return false;
    }
    else {  

        $('.login-fields').fadeOut();
        $('.login-form').spin("login", "#ffffff");      
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'assets/class/login/process.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:
            {
                username: $('input.username').val(),
                password: $('input.password').val()
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(!(data.lockdown == true)) {
                    if(data.error === true) {   
                        console.log(data.message);
                        $('.login-form').spin(false);
                        $('.login-fields').fadeIn();
                        $('.login-form').effect("shake", { distance: 40, times: 2 }, 100);
                    }
                        else {
                            console.log(data.message);
                            $('.login-form').spin(false);
                            $('.login-fields').fadeIn();
                            $('.content-login').fadeOut();

                            var structure = [
                                '<div class="after-login">',
                                    '<div class="inside">',
                                        '<div class="row-one">',
                                            '<h1>',data.message,'</h1>',
                                        '</div>',
                                        '<div class="row-two">',
                                            '<a class="cancel" href="',links.cancel,'?logout">Cancel</a>',
                                            '<a class="continue" href="',links.proceed,'">Continue</a>',
                                        '</div>',
                                    '</div>',
                                '</div>'
                            ];

                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $(structure.join('')).appendTo('section').fadeIn('slow');
                            }, 1500);

                        }
                }
                    else {
                        console.log(data.message);
                        $('.login-form').spin(false);
                        $('.content-login').fadeOut();

                        var structure = [
                            '<div class="system-lockdown">',
                                '<div class="inside">',
                                    '<div class="row-one">',
                                        '<h1>',data.message,'</h1>',
                                    '</div>',
                                    '<div class="row-two">',
                                        '<a class="back" href="',links.goback,'">Back</a>',
                                    '</div>',
                                '</div>',
                            '</div>'
                        ];

                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $(structure.join('')).appendTo('section').fadeIn('slow');
                        }, 1500);
                    }
            },
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown)
            {
                console.log('A PHP error triggered this, check your PHP log file for more information');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way to handle events with dynamically added content is with `on()`—or `delegate`, since you're on jQuery 1.6

```
$(document).delegate('.login-form .login', 'click', function(){
});
```

Note that this will listen to every single click anywhere in your document.  Ideally you'd like to identify some more narrow container from which **all** clicks will come, and listen to *that*.  So if all these clicks will be coming from your section, you'd do this

```
$("section").delegate('.login-form .login', 'click', function(){
});
```

Comment: I cannot use $.on, I still use 1.6.2 library, and @JamWaffles said it's available only from 1.7 or above.

Comment: I see, either way it works now. But my question is, is this method better that using $.live and why if it is ?

Comment: `live` is deprecated.  It will (it may - I hear it was optimized in some jQuery versions...) waste time going through everything currently in your dom matching the selector you pass it, wiring up events.  That's why `delegate` (and `on` in JQ 1.7) are preferable.  They just tell jQuery to wait around and watch click events that bubble up to `document` (or `section` in my second sample), and handle those that match the selector.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanations. I keep reading about this, but everyone has his own opinion ...

Comment: @Roland - here's a good article  http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/

Comment: Thank You :) Could I ask you something ? About var in js or jquery, is it ok if I declare multiple var like : `var a; var b; ...` or should I do : `var a,b,...`. I ask that because the var "a" would be in fact an object / array with multiple variables.

Comment: @Roland - If I understand correctly, I don't think it'd make any difference.  You want to do `var a = { "a": 12 }, b = [1, 2, 3], c = "Hello World";` ?  That'd be valid, but not very clean IMO. FWIW I'd put declarations like that should on their own line.  I'd save multiple declarations in one line for simpler things, like `var x = 0, y = 1, z = 2;`

Answer (score 2):

`$.click()` will only work on elements that have been created *before* the handler was created.

Instead, use [`$.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead:

```
$('.login-form .login').live('click', function() {
    // Your code
});
```

If you're using jQuery 1.7 or above, you can also use [`$.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in a similar way:

```
$('.login-form .login').on('click', function() {
    // Your code
});
```

Comment: I just tried it, it works fine. I first tried with $.delegate(), but it didn't work. No, I'm using 1.6.2 library, some of my plugins won't work with the newest library yet ... Thank you for the quick solution :)